# How to download APK from android market

Tags: google-play, apk

I am developing an application which requires another application to be installed on device.

if application  is not already installed on device **I want to download it(.apk file) from android market through my application and make it installed on device**.

how can I achieve it.

Comment: if there is any alternative way to remove this dependency please suggest.

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but there is a chrome browser extension called apk downloader ( see http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/ )

Comment: also this ( near end of the page ) http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1515021&page=3